# During which phase of the Asp.net control lifecycle or event the client,id are resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, custom-server-controls, checkboxlist

I developed a server control which is custom control inheriting from checkboxlist and implements the `IScriptControl` i use the controls `id`, `clientId` to set some properties used for rendering in client during the controls constructor but gosh both are null when i debugged them. So there should be something wrong , what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is during the Pre_Render stage that you can get the actual clientID and ID properties

```
public override void Pre_Render()
{

//control.ClientID and control.ID are available now

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Page` has an `InitComplete` event that should be fine to use outside of the Control, but the control itself looks to only have `Init` and `Load` events early enough in the lifecycle to tap into its properties

if you are setting other properties internally on the Control I would probably override the OnLoad method of the Control:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    //do your property setting here
}
```

Comment: i don't get it you are confusing me. Do i have to move the way up to Page to set them? or override the controls init event and set them there